# Beveled Plane Not Circular

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, bevel

I'm going to be creating a large number of 2D rectangles with rounded (beveled) corners. I was all set to use Ctrl-Alt-B on the corner vertices of a plane when I found that the bevels created are not truly circular.

By placing a 2x2 plane and then beveling the corners with an offset value=1.0, the resulting mesh should overlay an added mesh circle of the same size. This is not the case. (See image below)

Can anyone suggest a solution or an alternate way to easily create rectangular planes of varying sizes with truly circular corners using specific radii?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you changed the _Profile_ value of the bevel. I'd say it's set to somewhere around 0.6. Try setting it to 0.5.

Comment: It might be caused with how you beveled it; to get circle enable Clamp while beveling with C and increase the offset up to maximum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the bevel factor is set to a value of 0.5.
Also make sure your object's scale is applied in all axis.

[image: Bevel Factor]

Be aware that beveling a 2x2 units plane to a distance of 1 unit will likely create duplicate overlapping vertex at the edge midpoint that may cause problems down the road. It will also turn your four-sided face into a large NGon which is largely regarded as bad practice, and likely to create problems for animation and UV Mapping.

Comment: Thanks to the above commenters and to Duarte for posting as an answer. I had somehow set the Profile value to something other than 0.5 without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

A method I found that worked really quickly was just chhanging the preset.

When you bevel a corner, a pop up window shows up in Blender, and you can edit/change the bevel shape, by simply by changing the preset.

The preset 'Support Loops' will give you the rounded corner you're looking for, and the others, along with the curve editor just below it will let you manipulate it further if you wish.

[image: Bevel Pop-Up Window]